# How to insert data into Amazon Redshift using Aws Lambda Function(c# .net core)?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I found some c# code samples which requires OdbcConnection. But i cant use it in a .net core project(ODBC not supported as far as i know). Any hints or help will be gladly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: For those who use .net core..You can use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.

Comment: would be nice to show a code sample